# Ошибка при запуске бота для вк на node.js

Tags: node.js, вконтакте

```
const {VK} = require('vk-io');
const vk = new VK({
   token: '0ffd4bbbb124bb0b1f70b0f82035ce1fd29b149fd963baf6e32',
   apiMode: 'parallel',
   pollingGroupId: 198119776
});

vk.updates.hear(/^привет$/i, async (data) => {
    return data.send('привет');
});

async function run() {
    await vk.updates.startPolling();
    console.log('>_ Started');
}

run().catch(console.error);
```

при запуске бота в консоль выводится: "TypeError: vk.updates.hear is not a function"

Comment: Попробуйте vk().updates

Comment: TypeError: vk.updates is not a function

Answer (score 0):

Вместо этого

```
const {VK} = require('vk-io');
const vk = new VK({
   token: '0ffd4bbbb124bb0b1f70b0f82035ce1fd29b149fd963baf6e32',
   apiMode: 'parallel',
   pollingGroupId: 198119776
});
```

используй так:

```
const {VK} = require('vk-io');
const vk = new VK();
vk.setOption({
   token: '0ffd4bbbb124bb0b1f70b0f82035ce1fd29b149fd963baf6e32',
   apiMode: 'parallel',
   pollingGroupId: 198119776
});
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]